# How can I use constructor to write this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is about ellipsis in multiple text in responsive design.

I use jQuery to do it, but I think it will be more easier to write this code, but I have no idea to do it. I need some advice.

```
       if(responsive>1200 && responsive<1919){
            $(".ellipsis-2").each(function(){
                var maxwidth=15;
                if($(this).text().length > maxwidth){
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxwidth));
                    $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
                }
                console.log($(this).text().length);
            });
            $(".ellipsis-3").each(function(){
                var maxwidth=40;
                if($(this).text().length > maxwidth){
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxwidth));
                    $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
                }
                console.log($(this).text().length);
            });
        }else{
            $(".ellipsis-2").each(function(){
                var maxwidth=23;
                if($(this).text().length > maxwidth){
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxwidth));
                    $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
                }
                console.log($(this).text().length);
            });
            $(".ellipsis-3").each(function(){
                var maxwidth=53;
                if($(this).text().length > maxwidth){
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxwidth));
                    $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
                }
                console.log($(this).text().length);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a function to simplify your code, not really a constructor. Create one for the ellipsis logic receiving the selector for the elements to be applied as well as the max width:

```
function applyEllipsis(selector, maxWidth){
    $(selector).each(function(){
        if($(this).text().length > maxWidth){
            $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxWidth));
            $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
        }
        console.log($(this).text().length);
    });
}
```

Now you can call it inside your `if` statements passing the selector and max width that you need for each case:

```
if(responsive>1200 && responsive<1919){
    applyEllipsis(".ellipsis-2",15);
    applyEllipsis(".ellipsis-3",40);
}else{
    applyEllipsis(".ellipsis-2",23);
    applyEllipsis(".ellipsis-3",53);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add for OP's benefit that this is an example of the DRY coding principal, Don't Repeat Yourself. For further reading I suggest starting out at the [Wikipedia page for DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else is after this code you might find some use in storing your class/width values in an object array:

```
var ellipsisData = [
    {
        className: 'ellipses-2',
        smallWidth: 15,
        bigWidth: 23
    },{
        className: 'ellipses-3',
        smallWidth: 23,
        bigWidth: 53
    }
]
```

Then declare your function like the other answer:

```
var truncateText = function(className, maxWidth) {
    $("." + className).each(function() {
        if($(this).text().length > maxWidth) {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,maxWidth));
            $(this).html($(this).html()+'...');
        }
        console.log($(this).text().length);
    });
};
```

Now decide which width you want to use:

```
var widthKey = (responsive > 1200 && responsive < 1919) ? 'smallWidth' : 'bigWidth';
```

And finally iterate over your data elements and perform the function on each:

```
ellipsisData.forEach(function(ellipsis) {
    truncateText(ellipsis.className, ellipsis[widthKey]);
});
```

Unnecessary probably, but I'd already written it up so I figured I'd post it.